# What is the recommended build of hybrid should I use in APPIUM testing?

Tags: appium, pytest, appium-android, apache-cordova, python-appium

I create a hybrid app using apache cordova and I want to run some test using APPIUM (pytest).
Can I use the app build or the debug build for testing?
I really don't know what is the effect if I use the two different builds.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug build is recommended for testing because the complete symbolic debug information is emitted to help while testing applications because the code optimization is not considered.

Answer (score 1):

One is built in Release mode and one in debug mode. Now, it depends on you if you are using any tools that catch the logs generated by the app.

In release mode, you cannot get the app's logs, in debug mode you can get the debug logs.

For ex, if you wanna make sure that one particular set of the code block is executed, the developer can put a line of code which writes into log-like 'This code block is executed' etc.

It's best that you use debug since sometime an android app having pro-guard enabled may cause some problems for automation.

Comment: Can I use the release build if I disable it's pro-guard?